Cubic spline interpolation in Python - why is it not working?
I would like to apply a 2nd order low-pass Butterworth filter on my data, and then use cubic spline interpolation for resampling at every 1 meter in Python.
I tried to prevent having non-finite values but I still receive the following ValueError:
cs_v = CubicSpline(distance, filtered_v)     
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
raise ValueError("`x` must contain only finite values.")
ValueError: `x` must contain only finite values.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline, interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Butterworth filter
def butterworth_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=2):
    nyquist = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyquist
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y

# ensuring data arrays are finite
def ensure_finite(data):
    nans = np.isnan(data) | np.isinf(data)
    if np.any(nans):
        interp_func = interp1d(np.arange(len(data))[~nans], data[~nans], kind='linear', fill_value="extrapolate")
        data[nans] = interp_func(np.arange(len(data))[nans])
    return data


def handle_infinite(data, t):
    nans = np.isnan(data) | np.isinf(data)
    if np.any(nans):
        valid_mask = ~nans
        if valid_mask.sum() < 2:
            raise ValueError("No valid data.")
        interp_func = interp1d(t[valid_mask], data[valid_mask], kind='linear', fill_value="extrapolate")
        data[nans] = interp_func(t[nans])
    return data

# ...

data = pd.read_excel(r"xy")

t = data['Time'].values
x = data['X'].values
y = data['Y'].values
v = data['speed'].values  
z = data['altitude'].values
a = data['acceleration'].values
distance = data['distance'].values


# Set initial NaN value in distance to 0
if np.isnan(distance[0]):
    distance[0] = 0


# Ensuring distance array is increasing
sorted_indices = np.argsort(distance)
distance = distance[sorted_indices]
x = x[sorted_indices]
y = y[sorted_indices]
v = v[sorted_indices]
z = z[sorted_indices]
a = a[sorted_indices]

# Ensuring data arrays are finite 
v = ensure_finite(v)
a = ensure_finite(a)
z = ensure_finite(z)
x = ensure_finite(x)
y = ensure_finite(y)

# Butterworth filter
fs = 1 / (t[1] - t[0])  # sampling frequency
cutoff = 0.3  # frequency

filtered_v = butterworth_filter(v, cutoff, fs)
filtered_a = butterworth_filter(a, cutoff, fs)
filtered_z = butterworth_filter(z, cutoff, fs)


filtered_v = handle_infinite(filtered_v, t)
filtered_a = handle_infinite(filtered_a, t)
filtered_z = handle_infinite(filtered_z, t)


print(filtered_v)
print(filtered_z)


# Resampling
distance_new = np.arange(0, distance[0], 1)  # at every 1 meter


cs_v = CubicSpline(distance, filtered_v)
cs_a = CubicSpline(distance, filtered_a)
cs_z = CubicSpline(distance, filtered_z)
cs_x = CubicSpline(distance, x)
cs_y = CubicSpline(distance, y)

v_cubic = cs_v(distance_new)
a_cubic = cs_a(distance_new)
z_cubic = cs_z(distance_new)
x_cubic = cs_x(distance_new)
y_cubic = cs_y(distance_new)


To debug this: run your code in an interactive session / notebook, and directly after the exception, print the variable distance. Presumably it has some nan / inf values. If you can't figure out where they come from, maybe update the question.

It looks like I made a breakthrough and solved the problem. Thank you!

You can answer your own question. Self-answers are encouraged on SO. You will be able to accept your own answer after 48 hours.

So apparently, I could solve the problem.
Please find the relevant parts of my script for a 2nd order low-pass Butterworth filter with an adjustable cut-off frequency and resampling, using cubic spline interpolation, to achieve higher accuracy.
The method can be used for GPS data processing.
 import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Butterworth filter
def butterworth_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=2):
    nyquist = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyquist
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y


# Load data
data = pd.read_excel(r"")

t = data['Time'].values
x = data['X'].values
y = data['Y'].values
v = data['speed'].values  
z = data['altitude'].values
a = data['acceleration'].values
distance = data['distance'].values

# Set initial NaN value in distance to 0
if np.isnan(distance[0]):
    distance[0] = 0

# Ensuring distance array is increasing
unique_distances, indices = np.unique(distance, return_index=True)
unique_values = {dist: {'x': [], 'y': [], 'v': [], 'a': [], 'z': []} for dist in unique_distances}

for i in range(len(distance)):
    unique_values[distance[i]]['x'].append(x[i])
    unique_values[distance[i]]['y'].append(y[i])
    unique_values[distance[i]]['v'].append(v[i])
    unique_values[distance[i]]['a'].append(a[i])
    unique_values[distance[i]]['z'].append(z[i])

distance = np.array(list(unique_distances))
x = np.array([np.mean(unique_values[d]['x']) for d in distance])
y = np.array([np.mean(unique_values[d]['y']) for d in distance])
v = np.array([np.mean(unique_values[d]['v']) for d in distance])
a = np.array([np.mean(unique_values[d]['a']) for d in distance])
z = np.array([np.mean(unique_values[d]['z']) for d in distance])



# Butterworth filtering
fs = 1 / (t[1] - t[0])  # sampling frequency
cutoff = 0.1  # frequency

filtered_y = butterworth_filter(y, cutoff, fs)
filtered_x = butterworth_filter(x, cutoff, fs)
filtered_v = butterworth_filter(v, cutoff, fs)
filtered_a = butterworth_filter(a, cutoff, fs)
filtered_z = butterworth_filter(z, cutoff, fs)


# Resampling
if np.any(np.diff(distance) <= 0):
    raise ValueError("Distance array must be strictly increasing.")

distance_new = np.arange(0, distance[-1], 1)  # at every 1 meter

cs_v = CubicSpline(distance, filtered_v)
cs_a = CubicSpline(distance, filtered_a)
cs_z = CubicSpline(distance, filtered_z)
cs_x = CubicSpline(distance, x)
cs_y = CubicSpline(distance, y)

v_cubic = cs_v(distance_new)
a_cubic = cs_a(distance_new)
z_cubic = cs_z(distance_new)
x_cubic = cs_x(distance_new)
y_cubic = cs_y(distance_new)


min_len = min(len(t), len(x), len(y), len(v), len(z), len(filtered_x), len(filtered_y), len(filtered_v), len(filtered_z), len(filtered_a))
t = t[:min_len]
x = x[:min_len]
y = y[:min_len]
v = v[:min_len]
z = z[:min_len]
filtered_x = filtered_x[:min_len]
filtered_y = filtered_y[:min_len]
filtered_v = filtered_v[:min_len]
filtered_z = filtered_z[:min_len]
filtered_a = filtered_a[:min_len]

